# Difference between Aptana Studio standalone and Eclipse version

Tags: eclipse, ide, aptana-studio

I'm trying to download Aptana Studio (IDE) 3.6.1 for Windows from this link http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download.html but I do not really get the difference between the standalone version and the Eclipse plug in version. Is there a preferable one?

Also I do not really know what Eclipse is, and I've searched it here 
http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/Eclipse
but I still do not really get the idea of why there is another option in the download section of Aptana Studio for an Eclipse plug in version, what is that and what does it do?.

I will mostly use Aptana to write hardcore html, css, sass (SCSS), javascript and jQuery.

Comment: Eclipse is also an IDE. It happens to have an Aptana plugin. Only you can decide which is better for you.

Comment: @DavidPostill well it confuses  me more that an IDE has a plug in for another IDE what does that add of capabilities to Aptana, would you elaborate more in an answer ? and I do not that much about Aptana someone recommended it for me because it is free and cross platform  and I'm afraid that I download a version that does not suit my needs

Comment: I've no idea. I don't use either of them. They are both free, so you can try both and make you own mind up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should end up with the same thing.

The Aptana Studio download is just the basic Eclipse IDE with the Aptana plug-ins already added and the IDE branded as Aptana.

So if you don't already have Eclipse installed just use the full download. If you do already use Eclipse you can just install the plug-ins.